# is this the correct way to send data received from twitter api to the browser using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, browser

I am still learning nodejs and was listening to daniel shiffman's video on how to setup the twitter api and how to get data from it.
Now, the code was working and I was getting back data, but it was all happening in the terminal.
What I wanted to do was to show the twitter data in my browser and wasnt sure how to do that. I tried searching for it, but didnt get much help.
So, I just tried doing whatever I knew and it worked and therefore I am still not sure that the code I have written is the proper way to do this.
I'd love to know if there's a mistake somewhere or If there's some other way I should have done this.

Anyways, here's the code

```
 var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8080; // Use 8080 for local development because you might already have apache running on 80

console.log('The bot is starting');
var Twit = require('twit');
var config = require('./config');
console.log(config);
var T = new Twit(config);

var params ={
    q:'spider',
    count:5
}

T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);


function gotData(err, data, response) {
    var tweets = data.statuses;
    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        req=params;
        var tweetz='';
        for(var i=0;i<tweets.length;i++){
        console.log(tweets[i].text+'================================');
        tweetz = '<p>'+ tweetz+tweets[i].text+'</p>';

    }
    res.send(tweetz);
});


}


app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Comment: Try to read the tutorial here first https://expressjs.com/

Comment: I'd also appreciate it if you could just tell me what's the mistake instead of sending me a tutorial. I could have searched for express tutorial myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are doing is declaring `app.get` inside the callback.

`app.get("/", function....)` is a route which responds to `GET` requests which means whenever a user requests for "/", the callback which is the `function(req, res)` is called.

So the code should be:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    // User requested for "/" route, now get tweets
    T.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data) {
        //Tweets received, now send the tweets to the user
        var tweets = data.statuses;

        return res.send(tweets);
    })
})
```

Then go to `http://localhost:8080/` and it should work.

Comment: Okay thanks.
The truth is that the code IS already working. I just wanted to know the correct way to do things.
I included app.get inside the function because I know it's asynchronous and I have found a lot of times that variables end up getting no value if I have them outside the main function.
that's the reason I had put the app.get inside it.

So, was this the only mistake??

Comment: app.get defines a route (GET). Please read about Express and async javascript. You'll learn more. You are declaring route after calling the T.get. It may be working but I don't see the use of it as you are calling it with the same params. What is the user wants tweets with different params? For that he must supply the params, which he can do if the route is declared. So the flow is   Route -> all the functions -> return response.